# Why does generate_blob_sas() fail but generate_container_sas() works fine with the same values?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk, shared-access-signatures

I'm stumped. I'm attempting to use `generate_blob_sas()` function, but for some reason, the SAS token is malformed. I'm able to use the `generate_container_sas()` function with the same account, account key and container names. Seems to be the addition of the `stg_blob` name(?).

Thoughts?

**Example**:

```
import os

from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import urllib.parse


def generate_sas_token(stg_account:str, 
                       stg_container:str, 
                       stg_blob:str, 
                       stg_account_key:str,
                       token_perms:str,
                       token_duration:int) -> str:

        blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
                account_name = stg_account,
                container_name = stg_container,
                blob_name = stg_blob,
                account_key = stg_account_key,
                permission = BlobSasPermissions.from_string(token_perms),
                expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=token_duration)
            )
        return blob_sas_token


stg_account = 'myaccount'
stg_container = 'mycontainer'
stg_blob = '/folder1/folder2/blob.jpg'
stg_account_key = 'yeah'
token_perms = 'r'
token_duration = 10
```

The function executes successfully, but when the blob url + `blob_sas_token` are put into a browser, it results in the error below:

`https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/folder1/folder2/blob-name.jpg?se=2023-04-17T22%3A37%3A45Z&sp=r&sv=2021-12-02&sr=b&sig=<redacted>`

```
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:<longGUID> Time:2023-04-17T22:28:49.8347629Z</Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>
    Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2023-04-17T22:37:45Z /blob/<account-name>/<container-name>/<folder1>/<folder2>/<blob-name>.jpg 2021-12-02 b 
  </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

Comment: Please try with the following: `stg_blob = 'folder1/folder2/blob.jpg'`.

Comment: Cool, thank you @GauravMantri, that worked. The string processing I had in place was `stg_blob = parsed_url.path.split(stg_container)[-1]`, added `stg_blob = stg_blob.split('/', 1)[-1]` and that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

Initially, I tried with the same code and got the same error in my environment.

```
    <Error>
<Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
<Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:ee478ce7-601e-003c-61aa-71c892000000 Time:2023-04-18T04:03:05.1834825Z</Message>
<AuthenticationErrorDetail>Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2023-04-18T04:12:18Z /blob/venkat123/test/folder1/folder2/image1.png 2021-12-02 b </AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

[image]

I agree with Gaurav Mantri, you need to change the  `stg_blob = '/folder1/folder2/blob.jpg` to `stg_blob='folder1/folder2/blob.jpg`

Here is a workaround to get the SAS token with blob url using Python.

**Code:**

```
 import os    
 from azure.storage.blob import generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions
 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
 import urllib.parse   

 def generate_sas_token():
            stg_account = 'venkat123'
            stg_container = 'test'
            stg_blob = 'folder1/folder2/image1.png'
            stg_account_key = 'Your account key'
            token_perms = 'r'
            token_duration = 10

            blob_sas_token = generate_blob_sas(
                    account_name = stg_account,
                    container_name = stg_container,
                    blob_name = stg_blob,
                    account_key = stg_account_key,
                    permission = BlobSasPermissions.from_string(token_perms),
                    expiry = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=token_duration)
            )
            blob_url_with_sas = f"https://{stg_account}.blob.core.windows.net/{stg_container}/{stg_blob}?{blob_sas_token}"
            print(blob_url_with_sas)
    generate_sas_token()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Browser:**

The function executes successfully, but when the **`blob URL`** + **`blob_sas_token`** is put into a browser, I can able to see the image clearly.

[image]